# Consultas con funciones dinámicas Eloquent laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hola me encuentro preparando un API pero no puedo ejecutar algunas consultas que si o si tienen que ser dinámicas.

Se que se puede hacer algo como:

```
$mname = 'metodo1';
$prueba = new Prueba();
$prueba->$mname();
```

Por lo tanto intento hacer así las consultas:

```
$var = "where('id', '<', 10)"; // consulta dinamica
$var_2 = "where('name', '=', 'jorge')"; // consulta dinamica
```

Caso uno para utilizar una función.

```
$app = \DB::table('nombres')->select('id')->$var->get();
$app = nombres::select('id')->$var->get();
```

Caso dos utilizando la segunda función dinámica.

```
$app = \DB::table('nombres')->select('id')->$var2->get();
$app = nombres::select('id')->$var2->get();
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

```
**Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$where('id', '<', 10)"**
```

El motivo de porque lo hago de esta forma, es porque en el API llegan parametros de los cuales depende la información que debo de volver de mis tablas.

Lo que el usuario manda es un JSON

```
{
     limiters:{
         n: 50,
         betweenID: [0,10],
         ...
         ...
     },
     fields:['id','name']
}
```

Es algo parecido a graphql, por el momento no tengo autorizado implementarlo aparte de que no es compatible con laravel 5.7.

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent de Laravel ya es un constructor de querys, por lo tanto, ¿por qué no haces lo siguiente?

Crear un modelo para los nombres y crear los querys dependiendo de las condiciones que mencionas:

```
use App\Models\Nombre;

class Controlador extends Controller{

   public function consulta(){
      $registros = Nombre::query();
      if($condicion1){
         $registros = $registros->where('id', '<', 10);
      }
      if($condicion2){
         $registros = $registros->where('name', '=', 'jorge');
      }

      $registros = $registros->get();
   }
}
```

Comment: Es justo lo que estoy haciendo pero en lugar de hacerlo en un modelo lo estoy haciendo en un facade para así poder utilizar todos los modelos a la vez sin tener que hacer las relaciones.  Lo quería ejecutar desde un string porque es más fácil construir la consulta.

Comment: @AlbertoOrtega Si estás usando una base de datos relacional sugeriría fuertemente hacer las relaciones con los modelos, de otra forma, dejarías pasar toda la potencia que tiene Eloquent y el código que te ahorrarás...

Comment: @AlbertoOrtega Prueba con lo siguiente:

`$var = "{where}('id', '<', 10)"; 
   $app = \DB::table('nombres')->select('id')->$var->get();`

Comment: El problema es que tengo dos tipos de bases de datos. Tengo varias tablas SQL y unas en Mongo DB

Comment: Voy a probarlo esto {where}('id', '<', 10)

Comment: Puedes probar `->where(DB::raw($tuWhereDinamico));` haber si funciona.